# How to export all types of a sub-module into a new namespace?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, node-modules

While importing all types from a module with a custom-namespace seems to work great, like:

```
import * as MyCustomNamespace from './my-sub-module'
```

And we even can export all types from a module, without any new namespace, like:

```
export * from './my-sub-module'
```

#### But how can we achieve exporting all types of a sub-module into a new custom-namespace?

I mean, why does below not work:

```
export * as MyCustomNamespace from './my-sub-module'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did use a combination of both `import` and `export`, like below:

```
import * as MyCustomNamespace from './my-sub-module'

export { MyCustomNamespace }
```

But still, I would appreciate anyone pointing me out to a more correct and simple way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve

```
import { MyCustomNamespace } from 'submodule'
```

You need to modify a bit on your export inside that submodule

```
export * from './myCustomNameSpace'
```